# Crazy table or div...how do it? Or what use table or div?

Tags: html, tabular

I want to do it for my project.

[image: Table crazy!]

But how can I do it? Which method to use for make this? Div or table?

Comment: The answer is it depends. If you have six columns of data, by al means use a table. If you want to display blocks of identical info next to each other, use floating or inline-block divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best-practice to use properly styled divs.  Divs are cleaner and can be made responsive to resizing in ways that tables cannot (or at least not easily).

[Here is a much longer explanation of the subject in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html/84986#84986)